# Tab based Enable

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with 2 tabs, and a toolstrip button "open test image". How can I enable this toolstrip button only when Tab 2 [analysis] is open ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Selected event of the TabControl:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
  toolStripButton1.Enabled = (e.TabPage.Name == tabPage2.Name);
}
```

Of course, it probably makes more sense to put the button inside the TabPage, then you wouldn't have to worry about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This disables the button when the form loads:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnOpen.Enabled = false;
}
```

Then you can re-enable it by capturing the index of the tab that was clicked:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnOpen.Enabled = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedIndex == 1;
}
```